# XML LINQ Assistance

Tags: xml, linq

I am currently looking at XML and using it in C# and using it with LINQ.

I've got the following

My XML File

```
<RECSTEPS>
<RECSTEPS1>
    <STEP>Step 1 - prepare</STEP>
    <STEP>Step 2 - cut</STEP>
</RECSTEPS1>
<RECSTEPS2>
    <STEP>Step 1 - prepare</STEP>
    <STEP>Step 2 - cut</STEP>
    <STEP>Step 3 - Weld</STEP>
</RECSTEPS2>
<RECSTEPS3>
    <STEP>Step 1 - prepare</STEP>
    <STEP>Step 2 - cut</STEP>
</RECSTEPS3>
</RECSTEPS>
```

The code i am using is as follows:

```
string strFileName=@"\\wlfp02\home\CS4\nsavidge\Work\XML\test2.xml";

        XDocument xd =  XDocument.Load(strFileName);

        var t = xd.Descendants("RECSTEPS2");

        foreach (XElement xe in t.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xe.Value);
        }
```

This works fine, however, i am trying to use LINQ to do the same.  I get the same count, but cant get my hands on the ouput, i.e. whats inside the enumerable.  Ive had a look at the watch, but cant determine from that.

```
var t2 = xd.Root.Elements().Select(o => o.Element("RECSTEPS2"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. It should be:

```
var t2 = xd.Descendants("RECSTEPS2")
            .SelectMany(e => e.Elements());
```

In your query you are projecting each element of the root node to the value of the `RECSTEPS2` element. In other words, your query will return as many copies of the element `RECSTEPS2` as the number of elements under the root node.

What you were thinking of was *filtering*, i.e, using the `Where` operator, something like this:

```
var t2 = xd.Root.Elements()
            .Where(e => e.Name == "RECSTEPS2");
```

But the above will give you an `IEnumerable<XElement>` which match the criteria of being element `RECSTEPS2` (albeit only one does).
Put in other words, to iterate over the child elements of `RECSTEPS2` with the code above you'll need a double loop:

```
foreach(var parent in t2)
    foreach(var child in parent)
        Console.WriteLine(child.Value);
```

The benefit of using `SelectMany` is that it flattens the hierarchy of elements giving you only the child elements of `RECSTEPS2` node so your complete code would look like this:

```
var t2 = xd.Descendants("RECSTEPS2")
            .SelectMany(e => e.Elements());
foreach(var xe in t2)
    Console.WriteLine(xe.Value);
// Will print
// Step 1 - prepare etc
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, do yourself a favor and get [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It'll let you play with Linq queries and immediately get visual feedback of what your queries are doing.

The direct translation of your code to `Linq` is this:

```
IEnumerable<string> stepTwoSteps = xd.Root
                                     .Descendants("RECSTEPS2")
                                     .Elements()
                                     .Select (rs2 => rs2.Value);

foreach(string stepValue in stepTwoSteps)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stepValue);
}
```

Some things to consider though:

1. Is RECSTEPS2 always going to be directly under the root? If so, you're better off using `Elements("RECSTEPS2")` instead of `Descendants("RECSTEPS2")`, since the latter searches all depths of the XML structure where the former only looks immediately under the node it's used from.
2. Is there a chance that there will be more than one "RECSTEPS2" element? Know that your query will select both along with any "STEP" elements, which could make for duplication.

I'm guessing you're looking for something more along the lines of:

```
var stepTwoSteps = xd.Root
                     .Elements("RECSTEPS2")
                     .Elements("STEP")
                     .Select (step => step.Value)

foreach(string stepValue in stepTwoSteps)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stepValue);
}
```